# Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist, resultset

IDE Used:Netbeans 8.1.

Reading large data from MySQL database. Below is my code:

```
List outer=new ArrayList<String>();
List inner=new ArrayList<String>();
Connection con;
Statement stmt;
ResultSet rs;
ResultSetMetaData rsmd;
int columnNumber;
try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb","root","root");
    stmt=con.createStatement();
    rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from mytable where srno<1000");
    rsmd=rs.getMetaData();
    columnNumber=rsmd.getColumnCount();
    while(rs.next()){
        for(int i=1;i<columnNumber;i++){
            inner.add(rs.getString(i));
        }
        outer.add(inner);
    }           
    System.out.println("\t" + outer);
    rs.close();
    con.close();
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

I am getting error while running the code: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

I've tried to set vm options in properties>run>VM Options: -Xmx1024m

I am still getting the same error.How do I resolve it?

Comment: Query a smaller table or use a WHERE clause to limit how much data comes back.  Run 64 bit JVM with lots more RAM.  That's all you can do.

Comment: Did it. But still getting the same error.

Comment: Give more details about select result: how many rows? how many columns? average size of each column content?

Comment: There are total 10,67,000 rows and 45 columns.

Comment: As said from @e4c5 you need a different strategy

Comment: Suppose each column has an average size of `x bytes` you finish with `x*43MB`. If the average size of each column is 10 bytes you have 0,5GB in the heap. No way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just look at this code:

```
   while(rs.next()){
     for(int i=1;i<columnNumber;i++){
         inner.add(rs.getString(i));
     }
     outer.add(inner);
   }
```

For each row in the table, you are adding each column value into a list and each of those lists you are adding to another list. So if your table has 1 million rows and each row has 5 columns. You are creating 5 million rows. is it a surprise that memory is being exhausted? According to your update it's actually 10 Million rows and 45 columns. Do you realize that you are making 450 million objects!

Also remember that each item on the outer list will take more space than the amount of space those columns took on the database because of the object headers and other stuff.

You have explained what this is for, if it's for a swing app for example, you can choose a suitabl TableModel and avoid loading the whole db into memory at once.

Comment: Oh my mistake. I wanted to store whole row in a list and there are multiple rows, that's why did it this way.

Comment: A completely different strategy is needed.

Comment: I agree with @e4c5. You need to use data while you're reading from db (lazy list or paginated list). It's never a good strategy to load in memory data from a potential unlimited data source.